# Applying Edge Split Creates Double Vertices

Tags: modifiers, vertices, edges

Whenever I apply the Edge Split modifier to any object within a .blend, it creates double vertices. This issue follows the model regardless of which version and format (.3ds, .dae, .obj) it is exported to. (I tested with a 2.71 Nightly, 2.72b, and a 2.73 nightly)

Have any of you had this problem before and if so, how can it be fixed?

Comment: It seems you want to export normals data to present smooth and sharp faces. In that case, you have to manually assign Smooth/sharp to specific faces in Edit mode, then use formats like dae and obj, which support normals data storage. I don't think currently we got edge/vert normals supported for export, though you can already view/render within Blender. For edges, you may count on [this project](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mont29/Foundation/Split_Vertex_Normals).

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what [edge split](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Edge_Split) does, by definition.
Splitting one edge into two edges at the same location will make double vertices.

Comment: Huh, so it's always done that? The reason I ask is because I have been applying edge splits and using remove doubles in the past, but it has only recently started to remove doubles using it. I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry.

Comment: @FSLuaGuy Yep, it's always done that AFAIK. Note that removing doubles right after edge split will completely negate the effect of edge split, so it's a bit odd to use both one after the other..